# Center last row element using Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

When I resize the window to smaller resolution I would like the last element to be centered. I know that I can achive that by setting parent's `justify-content` parameter to `space-around` or `center`, but it has to be set to: `space-between`.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k7fzdn80/

Comment: isn't [this](https://jsfiddle.net/k7fzdn80/1/) what you want?

Comment: No, as I said: ul's justify-content has to be space-between.

Answer (score 8):

use auto margin

```
margin: 10px auto;
```

is this what you expect?
[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/fyvr33w8/)

Comment: Not exactly. I want the left element in top line to be aligned maximally to left side, and the right element to be aligned maximally to right side. In Your solution there's still a space between elements and margins.

Comment: This CSS property, applied to the last element, does the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible with `flexbox` for your  problem. But I have a CSS hack to solve the issue. Target the last element within the `media-query`. I have used custom breakpoints below.

```css
 ul {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
   padding: 0;
 }
 li {
   list-style-type: none;
   display: inline-block;
   min-width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
   margin: 10px;
 }
 @media (min-width: 376px) and (max-width: 494px) {
   li:last-child {
     margin: 10px auto;
   }
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. [`space-between` definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-justify-content-space-between) says

> If [...] there is only a [single flex](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) item on the line, this value
>   is identical to ['flex-start'](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-justify-content-flex-start).

The only way would be doing the alignment manually, e.g. with media queries and auto margins. But then the layout won't be flexible at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have another proposal. Using the [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to calculate the width of the flex item. And so the last element could be centered.

```css
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
        row-gap: 10px;
    }

    .column {
        display: flex;
        width: calc(100% / 4);
        overflow: hidden;

        text-align: center;
        background: green;
    }

    .inside-column {
        background: white;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin: 15px;
        border: 5px solid red;
    }

    .wrap {
      max-width: 350px;
      background: #CCC;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <a href="#" class="inside-column">
            1
            <br>Content Content Content
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="inside-column">
            2
            <br>Content Content Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="inside-column">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="inside-column">
            4
            <br>Content Content Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="inside-column">
            5
            <br>Content Content Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="inside-column">
            6
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="inside-column">
            7
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="inside-column">
            8
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="inside-column">
            9
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<br>
<br>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column">
            <a href="#" class="inside-column">
                1
                <br>Content Content Content
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="inside-column">
                2
                <br>Content Content Content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="inside-column">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="inside-column">
                4
                <br>Content Content Content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="inside-column">
                5
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="inside-column">
                6
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="inside-column">
                7
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="inside-column">
                8
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="inside-column">
                9
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```